# highchart sankey doesn't show in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I'm using highcharts in vuejs with highcharts-vue but a sankey diagram won't show up at all:

in my main.js I have done all necessary imports

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'
import sanKeyInit from 'highcharts/modules/sankey'
sanKeyInit(Highcharts)
import exportingInit from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
import exportDataInit from 'highcharts/modules/export-data'
import More from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'
exportingInit(Highcharts)
exportDataInit(Highcharts)
import dependencyWheelInit from 'highcharts/modules/dependency-wheel'
dependencyWheelInit(Highcharts)
treemapInit(Highcharts)
More(Highcharts)
```

in my vue component I can display a treemap but not the sankey diagram

Overview.vue

```
    <template>
    <v-container pa-0 ma-0>
    <v-layout column>
      <v-flex xs12>
         <v-container pa-0 ma-0 >
           <KeyValue :value="breadCrumb.join('>')" label=""></KeyValue>
         </v-container>
      </v-flex>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs6>
              <highcharts :constructor-type="'chart'" :options="treeMap" :callback="initMap" ref="treeMap"></highcharts>             
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs6>
              <!-- <highcharts :constructor-type="'chart'" :options="arc"  :callback="initCircles" ref="circle"></highcharts> -->
              <highcharts :constructor-type="'chart'" :options="wheel" :callback="initWheel"> 
              </highcharts>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
      
          </v-layout>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </template>
    <script>
     import vue from 'vue'
     import KeyValue from '@/components/KeyValue'

    export default {
       name: 'Overview',
       components: {
         KeyValue
       },
      
      data(){
       return {
       breadCrumb: [this.rootName],
       hashTree: {},
       charts: {treemap: null, circles: null, wheel: null},
       currentGraph: {nodeList: [], linkList: []},
       
       tree: [
         {name: 'thesponge', id: '2', value: 12, color: '#aaa'},
         {name: 'aa', id: '3', parent: '2', value: 34, color: '#aaa'},
         {name: 'ab', id: '4', parent: '2', value: 20, color: '#aaa'},
         {name: 'bob ', id: '5',  value: 45, color: '#a00'},
         {name: 'ba', id: '6', parent: '5', value: 40, color: 'red'},
         {name: 'bb', id: '7', parent: '5', value: 56, color: 'red'},
         {name: 'bba', id: '8', parent: '5', value: 40, color: 'red'},
         {name: 'bbb', id: '9', parent: '5', value: 56, color: 'red'},
         {name: 'bba', id: '10', parent: '8', value: 40, color: 'red'},
         {name: 'bbb', id: '11', parent: '8', value: 56, color: 'red'},
       ],
       arch: { '2': { nodeList: [{key: 'a', category: 'OfActivity', text: 'hello' },
                                 {key: 'ab', category: 'OfActivity', text: 'goodbye' }],
                      linkList: [{from: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'a'}, to: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ab'}},
                                 {from: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ab'}, to: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ac'}}
                      ]
       },
               '': { nodeList: [{key: 'a', category: 'OfActivity', text: 'miles' },
                                {key: 'ab', category: 'OfActivity', text: 'davis' }],
                     linkList: [{from: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'a'}, to: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ab'}},
                                {from: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'a'}, to: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ac'}}
                     ]
               },
               '5': { nodeList: [{key: 'a', category: 'OfActivity', text: 'john' },
                                 {key: 'ab', category: 'OfActivity', text: 'doe' }],
                      linkList: [{from: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'a'}, to: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ab'}},
                                 {from: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'a'}, to: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'a'}},
                                 {from: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ac'}, to: {nodeIdInCurrentGraph: 'ab'}},]
               }
       }
     }
   },
   computed: {
     wheel(){
       return {
         title: { text: 'Dependencies' },
         chart: {
           type: 'chart'
         },
         series: [{
           visible: true,
           name: 'country deps',
           
           keys: ['from', 'to', 'wheight'],
           /* data:[ this.arch[''].linkList.map((l)=>{return {from: l.from.nodeIdInCurrentGraph, to: l.to.nodeIdInCurrentGraph, weight: 1}})
            * ],*/
           data: [ ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 5],
                   ['Brazil', 'France', 1],
                   ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1],
                   ['Brazil', 'England', 1],
                   ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1],
                   ['Canada', 'France', 5],
                   ['Canada', 'England', 1],
                   ['Mexico', 'Portugal', 1],
                   ['Mexico', 'France', 1],
                   ['Mexico', 'Spain', 5],
                   ['Mexico', 'England', 1],
                   ['USA', 'Portugal', 1],
                   ['USA', 'France', 1],
                   ['USA', 'Spain', 1],
                   ['USA', 'England', 5],
                   ['Portugal', 'Angola', 2],
                   ['Portugal', 'Senegal', 1],
                   ['Portugal', 'Morocco', 1],
                   ['Portugal', 'South Africa', 3],
                   ['France', 'Angola', 1],
                   ['France', 'Senegal', 3]
           ],
           type: 'sankey',
         }]
       }
     },
     // ---
     treeMap() {
       return {
         title: { text: 'Navigate' },
         chart: {
           events: {
             load(){
               this.__proto__.vue.initTreeSeries()
             }
           },
         },
         series: [{
           type: 'treemap',
           layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
           allowDrillToNode: true,
           animationLimit: 1000,
           dataLabels: {
             enabled: false
           },
           levelIsConstant: false,
           levels: [{
             level: 1,
             dataLabels: {
               enabled: true
             },
             borderWidth: 3
           }],
           events: {
             setRootNode(){
               this.chart.__proto__.vue.updateCharts(arguments[0])               
             }
           },
           data: []
         }]         
       }
     },
    }
     
   },

   props: {
     rootName: {type: String, default: 'root'},
     width: {type: Number, default: 500},
     height: {type: Number, default: 500}
   },
  
   methods: {
  
     initWheel(chart){
       console.log("init wheel", chart)
       chart.__proto__.vue = this
       this.charts.wheel = chart
     },

     initMap(chart){
       this.hashTree = this.tree.reduce((mem,n)=>{
         n.children = []
         if(!n.parent) n.parent = ''
         mem[n.id] = n
         return mem
       },{})
       this.tree.forEach((n)=>{
         if(n.parent === '') return
         if(!this.hashTree[n.parent]) return 
         this.hashTree[n.parent].children.push(n)
       })
       chart.__proto__.vue = this
       this.charts.treemap = chart
     }
     
   }
 }
</script>
```

[result of sankey diagram in vuejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1T43.png)

Although the treemap shows properly, the sankey diagram doesn't

I've used the highchart debugger and yet no error.

Please help !!!

thanks

Comment: version of highchart is the latest : 8.2. I was wondering if I needed a licence to make it display properly ?

Comment: Could you try to reproduce it in an online code editor like codesanbox? Check this simple example with sankey in a Vue app: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-0otyk. try to simplify the code as much as you can.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply ... my guess is that i didn't import the higchart components inside my module bu inside the main.js only !!! yet i cannot reproduce for the moment, i'll check this out asap